# How to use complex search phrase in Facebook Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

The Facebook site allows to search for phrases like:

> Pages liked by people who are older than 50 and live in Munich,
>   Germany.

How can I do that with the Graph API? 
If this is not possible, do you know a workaround to do such searches automatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not do this at all.

The reason: Privacy.

You can not search all users of Facebook for demographic data this detailed.

In order to get what a user like you'll need the user to authorize your app to use "user_likes", which requires review.  [Source: Scroll down to "user_likes" section](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#categories)

In order to get anything other then under 18, or under/over 21 you'll need "user_birthday", which requires review. [Source: Scroll down to "Guidelines" on load then "ctrl+F" for "user_birthday"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#optimizing)

You can use "age_range" from public profile, doesn't require review, but this will only be for users that have authorized your app.  [Source: Age Range.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/age-range/)

In order to get a user location you'll need the user to authorize your app to use "user_location", which requires review. [Source: ctrl+F type "user_loction"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#reference)

You can use "locale" from public profile, doesn't require review, but this will only be for users that have authorized your app, and it will only show what language they use FB in.  [Source: Scroll down to "gender & locale" under "Public Profile"](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.3#reference)

All of what you want to do requires a Facebook review I doubt it will be approved. Next even if it did only those users that have installed/authorized your app will be available to your app. You absolutely can not open search user data like that with out the users permission.